# Callback function parameter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm writing a callback function for the [`FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog()`](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JS_API_M_FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog) function which accepts permissions and an optional callback function.

It's supposed to be passed `null` if the user rejects the permissions dialog. But for some reason, my script always makes the post request even if the permissions request failed.

```
echo("FB.ensureInit (  function () { 
        FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog('email,offline_access',
        function(accepted) {
             if(accepted==null) {alert('failure');} else {
             $.post(\"http://www.domain.com/permissions.php\",
                   { username:$userID,mode:'accepted'});}    
        });
        });");
```

Not sure why it's not reading the value of accepted properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is that the Javascript `null` value is not actually being returned, and some other false-like value is being returned instead.

I'd try changing to this to test for all false-like values:

```
if (!accepted) {alert('failure')} else { 
...
```

Comment: yea that worked great. says something about the facebook documentation though :P

Comment: Yeah I checked out that documentation.  Wasn't too great.

Answer (score 1):

Do with firebug:

```
console.log(accepted)
```

And see what you're getting back. Could be undefined, which according to your logic still passes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should change your logic around:

```
echo("FB.ensureInit (  function () { 
        FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog('email,offline_access',
        function(accepted) {
             if(accepted !== null) {
             $.post(\"http://www.domain.com/permissions.php\",
                   { username:$userID,mode:'accepted'});}
             } else {alert('failure');}
        });
        });
   ");
```